# Travel Consent Letter for US Domestic travel

Tags: air-travel, usa, paperwork, domestic-travel

I know that for international travel when a single parent takes a child out of the country the parent needs to have a travel authorization letter with them to be allowed to board the flight.

Does the same hold true for domestic travel in the US?  Does a parent leaving for another state needs to have a travel consent letter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The travel consent letter is addressed to immigration officers, who want to avoid that one parent kidnaps the child to another country without consent from the other parent, thus making it very hard to retrieve the child.

Traveling inside the country is much less of a risk, since there is no issue of lack of extradition treaties domestically. Also, as there are no domestic immigration checks in the US (unlike, e.g. in China), it is logistically much more difficult to catch domestic kidnapping - the [TSA doesn't even require children to show IDs for example](http://www.tsa.gov/traveler-information/acceptable-ids), though your airline [may still want to see some kind of ID](http://faa.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/9/session/L3RpbWUvMTQwNzU2NDAyMC9zaWQvaXI0LVZuX2w%3D), such as a birth certificate, or a passport.

TL;DR: No.

---

Note: A travel consent form can potentially be useful for domestic travel if you do not share a last name with the child to demonstrate that you're related in case of hospitalization at the travel destination.